# Algorithm for combining different age groups together based on their values

Tags: algorithm

Let's say we have an array of age groups and an array of the number of people in each age group

For example:

```
Ages = ("1-13", "14-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51+")
People = (1, 10, 21, 3, 2, 1)
```

I want to have an algorithm that combines these age groups with the following logic if there are fewer than 5 people in each group. The algorithm that I have so far does the following:

1. Start from the last element (e.g., "51+") can you combine it with the next group? (here "41-50") if yes add the numbers 1+2 and combine their labels. So we get the following

   ```
   Ages = ("1-13", "14-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41+")
   People = (1, 10, 21, 3, 3)
   ```
2. Take the last one again (here is "41+"). Can you combine it with the next group (31-40)? the answer is yes so we get:

   ```
   Ages = ("1-13", "14-20", "21-30", "31+")
   People = (1, 10, 21, 6)
   ```
3. since the group 31+ now has 6 members we cannot collapse it into the next group.
4. we cannot collapse "21-30" into the next one "14-20" either
5. "14-20" also has 10 people (>5) so we don't do anything on this either
6. for the first one ("1-13") since we have only one person and it is the last group we combine it with the next group "14-20" and get the following

   ```
   Ages = ("1-20", "21-30", "31+")
   People = (11, 21, 6)
   ```

I have an implementation of this algorithm that uses many flags to keep track of whether or not any data is changed and it makes a number of passes on the two arrays to finish this task.

My question is if you know any efficient way of doing the same thing? any data structure that can help? any algorithm that can help me do the same thing without doing too much bookkeeping would be great.

**Update:** 
A radical example would be (5,1,5)

in the first pass it becomes (5,6) [collapsing the one on the right into the one in the middle]

then we have (5,6). We cannot touch 6 since it is larger than our threshold:5. so we go to the next one (which is element on the very left 5) since it is less than or equal to 5 and since it is the last one on the left we group it with the one on its right. so we finally get (11)

Comment: Do you mean fewer than 5 in both groups or either group? I ask because I don't understand why 10 can't combine with 1, but 1 can combine with 10.

Comment: By convention, a group of (5, 1, 5) would become (5, 6) and not (6, 5), is that right?

Comment: If the one that we pick has more than 5 we do not collapse it, for example let's say there is one group smaller than "1-13" for example "0-1" that has 3 people. "14-20" cannot be grouped with "1-13" since "14-20" has 10 people. but since "1-13" has only one we collapse it with "0-1" even if "0-1" had 100 people. So we can only collapse a group with the next one if it has less than 5 people. If the last group has less than 5 and there is no group in the left we group it with the one on its right.

Comment: Could you specify the approaches you have tried?

Comment: @ user unknown it will become (5,6) first and since the one on the left is less than or equal to 5 we group it with again so we get one group (11)

Comment: And if 'Ages' ends in "51+", shouldn't it start with "-13", for symmetry? Which is "0-13"?

Comment: @Mark: You wrote 'fewer than 5' in the first paragraph after the first colored block. But that's not my point - let's take (7, 1, 8), which will lead to (8, 8), not (7, 9) - we aren't free to choose, where to put the single member? Because we start at 8 which isn't less than 5 (6), and move on, and combine it to the left, to the 7. My first idea was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my scala approach.
We start with two lists:

```
val people = List (1, 10, 21, 3, 2, 1)
val ages = List ("1-13", "14-20", "21-30", "31-40", "41-50", "51+")
```

and combine them to a kind of mapping:

```
val agegroup = ages.zip (people)
```

define a method to merge two Strings, describing an (open ended) interval. The first parameter is, if any, the one with the + in "51+".

```
/**
   combine age-strings 
   a+  b-c => b+
   a-b c-d => c-b
*/
def merge (xs: String, ys: String) = {
  val xab = xs.split ("[+-]")
  val yab = ys.split ("-")
  if (xs.contains ("+")) yab(0) + "+" else 
  yab (0) +  "-" + xab (1)
}
```

Here is the real work:

```
/**
   reverse the list, combine groups < threshold. 
*/
def remap (map: List [(String, Int)], threshold : Int) = {

  def remap (mappings: List [(String, Int)]) : List [(String, Int)] = mappings match {
    case           Nil =>      Nil 
    case x ::      Nil => x :: Nil 
    case x :: y :: xs  => if (x._2 > threshold) x :: remap (y :: xs) else 
      remap ((merge (x._1, y._1), x._2 + y._2) :: xs) }

  val nearly = (remap (map.reverse)).reverse

  // check for first element 
  if (! nearly.isEmpty && nearly.length > 1 && nearly (0)._2 < threshold) {
    val a = nearly (0)
    val b = nearly (1) 
    val rest = nearly.tail.tail 
    (merge (b._1, a._1), a._2 + b._2) :: rest
  } else nearly
}
```

and invocation

```
println (remap (agegroup, 5))
```

with result:

```
scala> println (remap (agegroup, 5))
List((1-20,11), (21-30,21), (31+,6))
```

The result is a list of pairs, age-group and membercount.

I guess the main part is easy to understand: There are 3 basic cases: an empty list, which can't be grouped, a list of one group, which is the solution itself, and more than one element.

If the first element (I reverse the list in the beginning, to start with the end) is bigger than 5 (6, whatever), yield it, and procede with the rest - if not, combine it with the second, and take this combined element and call it with the rest in a recursive way.

If 2 elements get combined, the merge-method for the strings is called.

The map is remapped, after reverting it, and the result reverted again. Now the first element has to be inspected and eventually combined.

We're done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an OCaml solution of a left-to-right merge algorithm:

```
let close_group acc cur_count cur_names =
  (List.rev cur_names, cur_count) :: acc

let merge_small_groups mini l =
  let acc, cur_count, cur_names =
    List.fold_left (
      fun (acc, cur_count, cur_names) (name, count) ->
        if cur_count <= mini || count <= mini then
          (acc, cur_count + count, name :: cur_names)
        else
          (close_group acc cur_count cur_names, count, [name])
    ) ([], 0, []) l
  in
  List.rev (close_group acc cur_count cur_names)

let input = [
  "1-13", 1;
  "14-20", 10;
  "21-30", 21;
  "31-40", 3;
  "41-50", 2;
  "51+", 1
]

let output = merge_small_groups 5 input
(* output = [(["1-13"; "14-20"], 11); (["21-30"; "31-40"; "41-50"; "51+"], 27)] *)
```

As you can see, the result of merging from left to right may not be what you want.

Depending on the goal, it may make more sense to merge the pair of consecutive elements whose sum is smallest and iterate until all counts are above the minimum of 5.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good data structure would be a linked list of pairs, where each pair contains the age span and the count. Using that, you can easily walk the list, and join two pairs in O(1).